# rake db:seed for some reason doesn't want to build association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in `seeds.rb`:

```
user = User.create({email: "test@mail.com", login:"test_account", password: "password123"})
    article=user.articles.build({:name=>"Test Article",
                            :description=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
                            :body=> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." ,
                     :approved => true})
    article.save!
```

But when I go to console:

```
2.1.1 :001 > Article.last
  Article Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Article id: 15, name: "Test Article", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin...", body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin...", approved: true, user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:55:58", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:55:58">
```

It has `user_id` equal to `nil`, which is not what I expect.

Strange thing. I can change syntax and use `user_id` instead of `build` method.

But when I add `:user_id => user.id` it is still nil, if I use :`user_id => User.last.id` nil again, but when I add `:user_id => 1` or any manual value it works. As If my last user had id nil, but it has id 2.

Comment: Is `user` actually being created? If there is a validation issue, the `user` would not be created, and would therefore give you all these problems.

Comment: @WesFoster, no, record is not valid if there was seed operation before, as it fails uniqueness validation. I use random string now, not sure if any other better option

Comment: After the seed, check if the user exists or not